# Mount command breaks when put into script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I am trying to mount something on startup using systemd, by running a simple command. When I run it through the terminal its fine, but when I put it into a file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) some_host_directory /home/user/some_dir
```

It gives an error:

```
mount: /home/user/some_dir: failed to parse mount options: No such file or directory.
```

But this directory exists, and as I mentioned above, if I run the exact same thing in the terminal directly then it works fine. What's wrong with putting it into a file?

Also if try to execute the script directly in the terminal it will produce the same error:

```
sh /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: It's complaining about the options, not the mountpoint argument, I think - my guess is that your system's `sh` doesn't set the UID variable (check with `sh -c 'echo uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g)'` for example)

Comment: Add `set -x` after basheng (`#!/bin/bash`) and you will see complete command before executing in debug.

Comment: I think you need root privs to mount a drive... how are you getting those?

Comment: @steeldriver is right, the UID variable was not set. Setting it manually fixed it

Comment: If `$(id -g)` works you should be able to replace `$UID` with `$(id -u)`